# Laravel redirect back leading to redirect loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-5.1

When user try to access url `/product/{product_id}/edit`, which is not permitted for that user, i have added a redirect back to previous URL with and an message,

```
public function edit($product_id)
{
...
return redirect()->back()->with(['error' => 'No permission']);
...
}
```

When user click on link( tag) it redirect back to previous url with error. But when user try to type URL `/product/12/edit` it keep redirecting to same url and become redirect loop.

How to properly resolve this problem, is it and laravel bug?

Answer (score 6):

Laravel, if HTTP_REFERER is not found, redirects user to the same url.
To avoid infinite looping, I used this approach:

```
$referer = Request::header('referer');
if(empty($referer)) {
  return Redirect::to(route('defaultRoute'));
} else {
  return Redirect::back();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If user clicks a link the current URL is passed as `'HTTP_REFERER'` and laravel uses it to redirect back, but if user types link directly into  browser address bar there will not be `'HTTP_REFERER'` and hence redirect loop.

You can use `route` to redirect to

```
return redirect(route('product.index'))->with(['error' => 'No permission']);
```

So user will always be redirected to index page.

Comment: Is any way to get previous request to Laravel which is not ajax?

Comment: @JithinJose Not quite getting your question :-)

Comment: I want to redirect back to previous request url from that user, excluding any ajax requests.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect back should be as follows:

```
return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'No permission');
```

ref: [larave doc](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#redirects)

Comment: It will not work if we load page without HTTP_REFERER header, It will redirect to same page and will eventually become redirect loop.